# How to make plot of m x n matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, plot

Here is the situation:

I have an array represented by list. Lets say:

```
a = [[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
```

and I would like to plot it into some visual representation (something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYSff.png)).

Please is there some simple way how to do this in python?

Edit:

I followed the first source code in [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/matshow.html) and my code looks like this:

```
arr = zeros((len(matrix), len(matrix[0])))
for i in xrange(len(matrix)):
    for j in xrange(len(matrix[i])):
    arr[i][j] = matrix[i][j]
matshow(arr)
```

Comment: Look at `imshow` from matplotlib.

Comment: I did, but no matter what I did, the code plot just nothing

Comment: show us your code which plots nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @Zhenya's answer works, I would use `matshow` rather than `imshow`

```
import pylab as plt
a = [[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
plt.matshow(a)
plt.show()
```

You don't have to call the `interpolation` argument and the axes are integers by default. See the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
>>> a = [[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.ion()
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.imshow(a, interpolation='nearest')
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x354ecd0>
>>> plt.draw()
```